# audio calling functionality using HMSSdk

Tags: ios, swift, audio, 100mslive

I am trying to develop audio calling functionality using HMSSdk , so if i have received call from user , bydefult speaker gets on of iphone.

I have tried to use  try hmsSDK.switchAudioOutput(to: .earpiece) as well , still no change , can anybody give any alternative to resolve this?